# Recursing nested array in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am attempting to loop out a menu in Laravel.

I am passing the nested array to the main blade template `categories-management.blade.php`.

`View::make('categories-management')->with('categories', $categories);`

Where `$categories` is

```
array (size=3)
  'Business Resources' => 
    array (size=7)
      'Operations' => 
        array (size=4)
          'resource_type_id' => int 1
          27 => 
            array (size=3)
              'id' => int 27
              'name' => string 'Design & Development' (length=20)
              'children' => 
                array (size=2)
               ... truncated ...
```

I am then kicking of the menu inside of `categories-management.blade.php` with this:

`@include('/includes/category-menu-item', array('categories', $categories))`

Inside `includes/category-menu-item` I have the following loop:

```
@if(is_array($categories))
<ul>
    @foreach($categories as $key => $value)
    <li>
        @if(!is_numeric($key)) 
            <p>{{$key}}</p>
            @include('/admin/includes/category-menu-item', array('categories', $value))
        @else
            <button data-category-id="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</button>
            @include('/admin/includes/category-menu-item', array('categories', $value->children))
        @endif
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

This is still obviously incomplete but I already have issues where the template never gets past the first layer and prints out:

- Business Resources

  - Business Resources

    - Business Resources

      - Business Resources

        ... etc ...

How do I get Laravel to recognise the new array value? Or is there a better method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@include` statements are not correct. The data passed to view need to be an **associated** array, you have passed an array with numeric keys. You have to change from `array('categories', $value)` into `array('categories' => $value)`:

```
@if(is_array($categories))
<ul>
    @foreach($categories as $key => $value)
    <li>
        @if(!is_numeric($key)) 
            <p>{{$key}}</p>
            @include('/admin/includes/category-menu-item', array('categories' => $value))
        @else
            <button data-category-id="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</button>
            @include('/admin/includes/category-menu-item', array('categories' => $value->children))
        @endif
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```